# Position sticky when the bottom of an element hits the bottom of the viewport

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a section that is always `100vh` or *more*:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section-sticky">...</div>
    <div class="rest-of-content">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section-sticky {
    position: sticky;
    min-height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
}
```

I want to make it fixed on the screen when the bottom of the section hits the bottom of the viewport. As for now, I am doing this by calculating the negative `top` value and applying it with JS:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var sectionHeight = $('.section-sticky').height();
var offset = windowHeight - sectionHeight;

if (offset < 0) {
  $('.section-sticky').css('top', offset);
}
```

however I feel this is an overkill and there should be a pure CSS solution. Any ideas?

PS: `bottom: 0;` doesn't work.
PSS: A working example: https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/pZoVpx.

Comment: @Pete the "or more" bit probably precludes that.

Comment: I can't stick it to the bottom with `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` because it is *at least* `100vh` and I'd need to scroll to see thw whole of it if it's not.

Comment: @Pete, overflow is not an optins because I don't want to end up with two scrollbars and position sticky looks like an ideal solution.

Comment: @BoltClock - if i'm understanding the problem correctly, bottom:0 won't work because the section can grow larger than 100vh and in that case, bottom:0 would place it below the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: Added a working example: https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/pZoVpx

Comment: @diopside: You are right.